# Using msSurv package in R

Tags: r, statistics, survival-analysis

I'm trying to use msSurv for a multi-state modelling problem that looks at an individuals transition to different stages. Part of that is creating a tree object which is where I think I'm making a mistake but I can't understand what it is. I'll include the minimum workable example here.

```
Nodes <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
Edges <- list("1" = list(edges = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6")),
"2" = list(edges = c("1", "3", "4", "5", "6")),
"3" = list(edges = c("1", "2", "4", "5", "6")),
"4" = list(edges = c("1", "2", "3", "5", "6")),
"5" = list(edges = c("3", "4", "6")),
"6" = list(edges = NULL))
treeobj <- new("graphNEL", nodes = Nodes, edgeL = Edges, edgemode = "directed")
fit3 <- msSurv(df, treeobj, bs = TRUE, LT = TRUE)
```

The error I'm getting is as follows.

```
No states eligible for exit distribution calculation.
Entry distributions calculated for states 6 .
Error in bs.IA[, , j, b] : subscript out of bounds
```

The dataset in question can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArrhKTNddU2CcSglHvirf0uRoYU?e=AXX1b5).

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: also you should include all packages you use for this problem and do not post a link to a data set. Instead use `dput(data)`- copy and paste output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding, but your 6 group doesn't have 1-6 as an edge, thus the program returns an error because in essence you're saying 6 isn't connected to the calculation. In relation to the solution, I believe 6 should have edges, as in this line may need to have edges: `"6" = list(edges = NULL))`